# Matrices with the same spectral moments but different size

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations

Let $A$ and $B$ be two square matrices and suppose they have the same spectral moments, i.e.,

$$
tr(A^k) = tr(B^k), \, \forall k \in \{1,2,\ldots\}.
$$

If, additionally, $A$ and $B$ have the same size $n$, then using the [Newton's Identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_identities#Application_to_the_characteristic_polynomial_of_a_matrix) we see that the characteristic polynomial of $A$ must equal that of $B$. Therefore, $A$ and $B$ have the same eigenvalues, up to algebraic multiplicity.

I am interested in the case where $A$ and $B$ are **NOT** the same size, but have the same spectral moments. One trivial example is where $B$ is simply $A$ but with an added row and column filled with zeros. In this case, it is obvious that the spectral moments are equal as they do not depend on the multiplicity of the zero eigenvalue. Are there any non-trivial examples?

More generally, given a square matrix $A$, I am interested in the class of all matrices $B$ such that $B$ has the same spectral moments of $A$, regardless of its size. Is there a class of transformations that fixes only the non-zero eigenvalues?

Comment: Also, if $A=0$ and $B$ is nilpotent, but nonzero, gives such cases of arbitrary size.

Comment: Yes! Thanks for pointing that out. In general, if the spectrum of $A$ and $B$ differ only in the multiplicity of zero, then the spectral moments are the same. I am interested in the case when the non-zero eigenvalues are also different, but the spectral moments are still the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just pad them with zeroes until they're the same size to reduce to the previous case. The conclusion is that their characteristic polynomials are the same up to factors of $t$. Equivalently, two matrices have the same spectral moments iff they have the same *nonzero* eigenvalues, with the same multiplicities. For example, you can take the direct sum with a nilpotent matrix.

An interesting class of examples here is that we can take $A = CD, B = DC$ where $C, D$ are two matrices, not necessarily square. $CD$ and $DC$ always have the same characteristic polynomial up to factors of $t$, although this is not entirely obvious. It's more obvious that they have the same spectral moments, since we clearly have $\text{tr}((CD)^k) = \text{tr}((DC)^k)$ by cyclicity of the trace.